# Codeigniter multiple file upload with image resizing/thumnail creation

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple images, re-size those images, then create thumbnails for the images via codeigniter.

```
$config['upload_path'] = '---path---';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

$this->load->library('upload');

$files = $_FILES;
$cpt = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
{
    $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $files['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['error']= $files['files']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];    

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('files');
    $tmp = $this->upload->data();

        $this->load->library('image_lib'); 
        //Thumbnail configs
        $config_t['source_image']   = '---path---' . $tmp['file_name'];
        $config_t['new_image']  = '--path to thumbnail ---' . $tmp['file_name'];
        $config_t['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config_t['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config_t['width']   = 110;
        $config_t['height'] = 110;
        //end of configs

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_t); 
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config_t);
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();

        //Resize Configs
        $config_r['source_image']   = '----path----' . $tmp['file_name'];
        $config_r['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config_r['width']   = 800;
        $config_r['height'] = 800;
        $config_r['quality']    = 100;
        //end of configs

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_r); 
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config_r);
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();

}
```

The image uploading works fine, every image gets uploaded, the problem is the image manipulation:

No errors are displayed, however the images aren't being being resized to 800x800 px or 100x100

EDIT::

The images are getting copied into the thumbnail folder, they just had the _thumb rename. However, the thumbnail images are being re-sized to "something" by 800px, EX:

1289px by 800px

they should be 100px by 100px, the original image is still not being re-sized

EDIT::

If I remove the re-size configs:

```
//Resize Configs
        $config_r['source_image']  = '----path----' . $tmp['file_name'];
        $config_r['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config_r['width']  = 800;
        $config_r['height']    = 800;
        $config_r['quality']   = 100;
        //end of configs

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_r); 
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config_r);
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();
```

the thumbnail re-size/upload works perfectly, just need to figure a way to do both

Comment: Did you check directory permission ?

Comment: Both directories are 777

Comment: Did you check `$config_r['source_image']` exists your path is correct why don't you just replace this `'----path----' . $tmp['file_name']` with this `$tmp['full_path']`

Comment: great suggestion, however I tested every path and they both are valid. I got the thumbnail to work, I just can't figure out a way to do the re-sizing at the same time

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path'] = '---path---';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

$this->load->library('upload');

$files = $_FILES;
$cpt = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
{
    $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $files['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['error']= $files['files']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];    

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('files');
    $tmp = $this->upload->data();

        $this->load->library('image_lib'); 
        //Thumbnail configs
        $config_t['source_image']   = '---path---' . $tmp['file_name'];
        $config_t['new_image']  = '--path to thumbnail ---' . $tmp['file_name'];
        $config_t['create_thumb'] = FALSE;///change this
        $config_t['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config_t['width']   = 110;
        $config_t['height'] = 110;
        //end of configs

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_t); 
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config_t);
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();

        //Resize Configs
        $config_r['source_image']   = '----path----' . $tmp['file_name'];
        $config_r['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config_t['create_thumb'] = FALSE;///add this
        $config_r['width']   = 800;
        $config_r['height'] = 800;
        $config_r['quality']    = 100;
        //end of configs

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_r); 
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config_r);
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache after resizing it again?

```
$this->image_lib->resize()
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

just load the library once and use the `initialize.` then clear it after every resize

```
    $config_t['source_image']   = '---path---' . $tmp['file_name'];
    $config_t['new_image']  = '--path to thumbnail ---' . $tmp['file_name'];
    $config_t['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config_t['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config_t['width']   = 110;
    $config_t['height'] = 110;

    $config_r['source_image']   = '----path----' . $tmp['file_name'];
    $config_r['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config_r['width']   = 800;
    $config_r['height'] = 800;
    $config_r['quality']    = 100;
    //end of configs

    //load library once
    $this->load->library('image_lib'); 

    //use first config
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_t);
    //run resize
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
      echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    //clear
    $this->image_lib->clear();

    //initialize second config
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_r);
    //run resize
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    //clear
    $this->image_lib->clear();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, calling $this->image_lib->clear(); did the trick